# Leaflet.js - Create layers and add markers depending on geojson category data?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, layer

I have a .js file with coordinates for internships:

```
var internships = [{
  "features": [
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"category":"entretient","Name":"green"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[50.807149, 3.162994]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"category":"securité","Name":"blue"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[50.334421, 3.290146]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"category":"secretaria","Name":"red"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[50.744787, 2.256216]}}
  ]
}];
```

I've found this bit of code allowing me to create layers depending on a property and here what my JS looks like:

```
$.getScript("CoordinatesPdC.js");

function mapLoad() {
  var sécuritéLayer = new L.LayerGroup();
  var secrétariatLayer = new L.LayerGroup();
  var entretientLayer = new L.LayerGroup();

  var map = L.map('map').setView([50.2910, 2.7775], 8);

  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, '
  }).addTo(map);

  var marker = L.marker([50.2910, 2.7775]).addTo(map);

  var entretientLayer = L.geoJson(internships, {
    filter: function (feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.category === "entretient");
    }
  }).addTo(map);

  var sécuritéLayer = L.geoJson(internships, {
    filter: function (feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.category === "sécurité");
    }
  }).addTo(map);

  var secrétariatLayer = L.geoJson(internships, {
    filter: function (feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.category === "secrétariat");
    }
  }).addTo(map);

}

window.onload = mapLoad;
```

But now I have to create the markes assigned to these layers, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markers are already assigned to each later. In your example, you create a layer (with all of its markers) and immediately add it to the map using **`.addTo(map);`** Here's the code responsible for it.

```
var sécurité = L.geoJson(internships, {
  filter: function (feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.category === "sécurité");
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Now, you probably want to only display a certain layer based on user input. If so, I suggest adding the related layer to the map on a click event. Then when the event is triggered a layer is added. Here's the code for doing that. `sécurité.addTo(map)`
A layer is removed using `map.removeLayer(sécurité);`

Below is a working example based on your initial code. *(I did write it in jQuery as my vanilla JavaScript could be better)* You can also view it on [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/roycode/6prcs5zu/).

I left some comments in the code to explain what each part does. I hope that helps you with your understanding.

```js
var internships = [{
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "entretient",
        "Name": "green"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [3.162994, 50.807149]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "securité",
        "Name": "blue"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [3.290146, 50.334421]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "category": "secretaria",
        "Name": "red"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [2.256216, 50.744787]
      }
    }
  ]
}];

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Create an object to keep track of active layers and each layer with its markers
  const layers = {
    active: [],
    entretientLayer: new L.LayerGroup(),
    sécuritéLayer: new L.LayerGroup(),
    secrétariatLayer: new L.LayerGroup(),
  };

  // create the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([50.8010, 3.1675], 6,5);

  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
      '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, '
  }).addTo(map);

  // based on the category assign a marker to the layer
  layers.entretientLayer = L.geoJson(internships, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.category === "entretient");
    }
  })

  layers.sécuritéLayer = L.geoJson(internships, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.category === "securité");
    }
  })

  layers.secrétariatLayer = L.geoJson(internships, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.category === "secretaria");
    }
  })

  // register click event
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    const layerName = e.target.name;

    // if a layer is already active, remove it from the map and the active array
    if (layers.active.includes(layerName)) {
      layers.active = layers.active.filter(layer => layer !== layerName);
      map.removeLayer(layers[layerName]);
    } else {
      // add the layer to the map and to the active array
      layers.active.push(layerName);
      layers[layerName].addTo(map);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.3/leaflet.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.3/leaflet-src.js"></script>


<div class="button-group">
  <button name="entretientLayer">entretient</button>
  <button name="sécuritéLayer">sécurité</button>
  <button name="secrétariatLayer">secrétariat</button>
</div>
<p></p>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** updated leaflet.js to version 1.3.3.
The difference with the update is that each layer needs to be initialised using the `new` key word. Code is updated to reflect the change.

Comment: I have a problem with the code, when I put it on any IDE I have it doesn't work, the map doesn't show up, is that normal?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Make sure you the code runs after the `<div id="map"></div>` element is rendered, else the map won't show.

Comment: I found why it didn't work, it's because you use 0.7.1 of leaflet while I use 1.3.3, on the most recent version your code doesn't work, so as long as I use 0.7.1 it works

Comment: Ow, wow, I didn't even realise I used an older version from the CDN. I've updated the answer to be able to use the latest version. Give that a try.

Comment: works perfectly as intended! thank you for your help!